# drupal views restore issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I had a view which had a number of displays. I clicked on "Remove display" one of them and saved the changes. Now when i go to that display, the "Fields" area is greyed out. How can i restore the display back to original ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but once you click save for the view, and then return to the view it'll go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a display then click "Remove Display" and save the changes to the view, you should no longer see it in the list of displays for that view (hence *removing* the display).

After clicking "Remove Display," you can only restore the display *before* saving the whole view.